# TypeError: (0 , marked__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.default) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have updated my project from Next.js 10 to 12. Among all the changes, one of my sections stops working, particularly, the one that generates pages from a markdown file. I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: (0 , marked__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.default) is not a function
```

[image]

My Next.js Javascript template is:

```js
/** @format */
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import matter from 'gray-matter';
import Head from 'next/head';
import marked from 'marked';
import { defaultLocale } from '../../i18n.json';
import useTranslation from 'next-translate/useTranslation';

import Header from '../../components/ui/Header/Header';
import Footer from '../../components/ui/Footer/Footer';
import Main from '../../components/ui/Main/Main';

const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), '__docs');

export default function Doc({ htmlString, data }) {
  let { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>
          {data.title} – {t('common:version', { version: data.version })}
        </title>
        <link rel='icon' href='/favicon.png' />
      </Head>

      <Header background='1' elevation='4' />
      <Main css='padding--16 display--grid'>
        <h1>{data.title}</h1>
        <div
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlString }}
          className='color--gray line-height--24'
        />
        <hr />
        <p className='color--gray line-height--24'>
          {t('common:version', { version: data.version })}. Last update:{' '}
          {data.date}
        </p>
      </Main>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export const getStaticPaths = async ({ locales }) => {
  let paths = [];

  const docs = fs.readdirSync('__docs');
  console.log(docs);

  for (let slug of docs) {
    for (let locale of locales) {
      let fullpath = path.join(
        postsDirectory,
        slug,
        locale === defaultLocale ? 'index.md' : `index.${locale}.md`
      );

      if (!fs.existsSync(fullpath)) {
        continue;
      }

      paths.push({ params: { slug }, locale });
    }
  }

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params: { slug }, locale }) => {
  // we need to find and read the file
  const filename = locale === defaultLocale ? 'index.md' : `index.${locale}.md`;
  const markdownWithMetadata = fs
    .readFileSync(path.join(postsDirectory, slug + '/' + filename))
    .toString();
  // we parse the content to strip the metadata
  const parsedMarkdown = matter(markdownWithMetadata);
  // we parse the content to convert it to html with marked
  const htmlString = marked(parsedMarkdown.content);
  return {
    props: {
      htmlString,
      data: parsedMarkdown.data,
    },
  };
};
```

My current package.json is this one:

```json
{
  "name": "Minide",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.3",
    "marked": "^4.0.5",
    "mdx": "^0.3.1",
    "next": "12.0.4",
    "next-translate": "^1.2.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-number-format": "^4.8.0",
    "remark": "^14.0.2",
    "remark-html": "^15.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "7",
    "eslint-config-next": "^12.0.4"
  }
}
```

I have updated React, and I also tried to import React on the page, but it didn't work at all. Next.js imports react by default but in another component, I had to force import, and when I use import React from 'react' on the template i go from MODULE_7 to MODULE_8.

```
TypeError: (0 , marked__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.default) is not a function
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `.next` folder and running `npm run dev` again?

Comment: @juliomalves yes, I did and I receive a different error this time (0 , marked__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.default)

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem. You imported `marked` wrong. As it says on the remark documentation, you should do this instead `import { marked } from 'marked';`

[image]

Comment: You are right but you're linking and showing code for the wrong library, the issue is with [`marked`](https://marked.js.org/#installation) not `remark`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what went through my mind but your bug comes from this error. I just modified the answer. It’s going to work for sure.

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem. It is solved now!